# CSS Media Query not working with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have created a navigation menu using bootstrap, but when I try to hide a div inside the nav header based on media query, it won't work.

The div in concern has the class `.hide-on-desktop`.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse5" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle cls1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="cls2">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-tumblr" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-vimeo-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-rss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <div class="hide-on-desktop">
                This sentence should only show on smaller devices.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse5" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form class="form1">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Text Here...">
                <button><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </form>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header .fa {
  color: grey;
}

header {
    background-color: #000;
}

@media (min-width: 200px) {
    .cls1 {
        float: left;
    }
    .cls2 {
        float: right;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .hide-on-desktop {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap already has built in classes to do this, these follow the same screen sizes of the other bootstrap classes and will hide elements in those screen sizes.

```
Classes       |  Extra small devices Phones (<768px) | Small devices Tablets (≥768px) | Medium devices Desktops (≥992px) | Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)|
______________|______________________________________|________________________________|__________________________________|_________________________________|
.visible-xs-* |  Visible                             |    Hidden                      |   Hidden                         |  Hidden                         |
______________|______________________________________|________________________________|__________________________________|_________________________________|
.visible-sm-* |  Hidden                              |    Visible                     |   Hidden                         |  Hidden                         |
______________|______________________________________|________________________________|__________________________________|_________________________________|
.visible-md-* |  Hidden                              |    Hidden                      |   Visible                        |  Hidden                         |
______________|______________________________________|________________________________|__________________________________|_________________________________|
.visible-lg-* |  Hidden                              |    Hidden                      |   Hidden                         |  Visible                        |
______________|______________________________________|________________________________|__________________________________|_________________________________|
.hidden-xs    |  Hidden                              |    Visible                     |   Visible                        |  Visible                        |
______________|______________________________________|________________________________|__________________________________|_________________________________|
.hidden-sm    |  Visible                             |    Hidden                      |   Visible                        |  Visible                        |
______________|______________________________________|________________________________|__________________________________|_________________________________|
.hidden-md    |  Visible                             |    Visible                     |   Hidden                         |  Visible                        |
______________|______________________________________|________________________________|__________________________________|_________________________________|
.hidden-lg    |  Visible                             |    Visible                     |   Visible                        |  Hidden                         |
______________|______________________________________|________________________________|__________________________________|_________________________________|
```

Maybe it will help you to see how the bootstrap library defines one of these classes:

```
.hidden-xs {
  display: block !important;
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

They set the property as important and they use max width instead of min width. that means "This css will be applied until a maximum screen width of 767px".

Answer (score 0):

Change **media query** with this:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check the Bootstrap official documentation regarding this, They explain everything you need.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities

Example:

```
.visible-xs 
.visible-sm 
.visible-md 
.visible-lg 
.hidden-xs  
.hidden-sm  
.hidden-md
.hidden-lg
```

Another Sample Example of using these classes..

```
<div>Using hidden</div>
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-md">hidden-sm hidden-md</div>
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-lg">hidden-sm hidden-lg</div>
<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">hidden-md hidden-lg</div>
<div>Theoretical equivalent using visible</div>
<div class="visible-lg">hidden-sm hidden-md</div>
<div class="visible-md">hidden-sm hidden-lg</div>
<div class="visible-sm">hidden-md hidden-lg</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this only !

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.hide-on-desktop {
    display:none;
}    }
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vajckx91/)

As your wish change pixels in this one to hide.